# What does "highlights & lowlights" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am invited for an HR interview. and the interviewer asked me to prepare myself for the below question:

***Prepare yourself to give examples of your `highlights & lowlights` at work***

i am wondering, what does `highlights & lowlights` in this context mean?

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question, because it involves a little misdirection.

The basic term is *highlight* and *lowlight* is an extension of that.

> **highlight** *n*
>   2. An especially significant or interesting detail or event.
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/highlight)</sub>

The term is originally from painting, meaning a bright spot in a darker area—in other words, an area of "high light." From [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/highlight#etymonline_v_12000):

> 1650s, originally of paintings, "the brightest part of a subject," from *high* (adj.) + *light* (n.).

It came to mean something interesting or significant in a figurative sense before being adopted as a literal denotation.

Then, since we had a term for something, the obvious opposite presented itself: *lowlight*. This term has been figurative for quite a while (Etymonline has no entry for it), but some sources are coming to accept it in its own right:

> **lowlight** *n*
>   an unenjoyable or unpleasant part of an event
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lowlight)</sub>

What the interviewer is almost certainly interested in is a narrative about your successes and failures on the job: what you did well and what you could have done better.

Comment: Compare "rule out" - a reference to a now dead practice of drawing a straight line through some item  in a list to eliminate it - and the new term 'rule in' which makes no sense at all in the context of the original metaphor but has come to mean to opposite of 'eliminate'.